# How retain responses on promise chaining with Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, q

I have a process with has two database call, that need to be in order. Finally, I need to merge the last two response in a single one.

I am using flat promise chaining, and i don't know how return the current and previous promise.

I have something like this:

```
let deferred = Q.Promise();

this.methodA('somevalue')    
.then(firstResponse => {
    return this.methodB(firstResponse.prop1);    
}).then(secondResponse => {
    return this.methodC(secondResponse.prop2);    
}).then(finalResponse => {
    //Here I need firstResponse and secondResponse... meaby wrapped inside finalResponse
    let response = {
        prop1: finalResponse.firstResponse.prop1,
        prop2: finalResponse.secondResponse.prop2
    };
    deferred.resolve(response);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

PS: This is in TypeScript. I deleted a lot of code to do a simple example about  I looking for.

Comment: do you need the result of methodC? where is it sent in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return both the firstResponse and the result of `methodB`:

```
let deferred = Q.Promise();

this.methodA('somevalue')    
  .then(firstResponse => {
    return Q.all([this.methodB(firstResponse.prop1), Q(firstResponse.prop1)];    
  }).then(secondResponse => {
    return Q.all([this.methodC(secondResponse[0].prop2, Q(secondResponse[1])]);    
  }).then(finalResponse => {
    //Here I need firstResponse and secondResponse... meaby wrapped inside finalResponse
  let response = {
    prop1: finalResponse.firstResponse.prop1,
    prop2: finalResponse.secondResponse.prop2
  };
  deferred.resolve(response);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: the `deferred` object is actually unnecessary here, as are some of the intermediate values afaik,